# Table cols definition

Tags: kdb, k

There are a bunch of tricks used in kdb+ to work with keyed/splayed/partitioned and simple tables. I see lots of `.Q` functions which work as a facade for these varieties. One of them is `cols`. Could you help me please with one of the cases - what the `11h=` case stands for?

```
cols
k){$[
  .Q.qp x:.Q.v x; / If partitioned
  .Q.pf,!+x;      /   add "partitioned field" to table cols
  98h=@x;         / If simple table
  !+x;            /   just table cols (convert to dict of lists, get keys)
  11h=@!x;        / ?
  !x;
  !+0!x           / (keys-dict)!(data-dict): remove keys, get table cols
  ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for dictionaries:

```
q)cols`a`b`c!1 2 3
`a`b`c
```

Where the type (`@`) of the key  (`!`) is a list of symbols (`11h`)